# Proving integrals of $f(\sin(x))$ and $f(\cos(x))$ are equal

Tags: calculus, integration

> Prove that for every continuous function $f$, $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(\sin(x))dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(\cos(x))dx $.

I am not really sure how to tackle this, but nevertheless here is
my attempt;

If we let $\mu = \sin(x)$ then $d\mu/dx = \cos x \rightarrow d\mu = \cos(x)dx$.

That means that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(\sin(x))dx = \int_{0}^{0} \frac{f(\mu)}{\cos x}d\mu = \frac{1}{\cos x}\int_{0}^{0} f(\mu)d\mu$

and the left hand side can also be written as $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\cos x}\int_{0}^{0} f(\mu)d\mu$ by substituting $\mu = \sin(x)$.
$\blacksquare$

I am not sure if this correct. I may have missed something or if by chance this happens to be correct is there a better proof perhaps?

Thanks.

Comment: There is alot of mistakes/typos here: strange integration limits $\int_0^0 $, $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ outside of the integral, what is $u$? Look over your post one more time and edit it!

Comment: I have changed the $u$ to $\mu$; but your reasoning is completely flawed, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 13):

Just use the substitution $y=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$. You have $dx=-dy$ and $\sin x=\cos y$.

Comment: This is very neat! But is there a problem with my solution?

Comment: Yes, indeed ! All $x$'s must be replaced by $u$'s.

Comment: But they have been in my solution

Comment: You still have $\frac{1}{cos x}$ as a part of your solution, you cannot have $x$ in the expresison when you have made a substitution

Answer (score 1):

You may just use $\cos (\pi/2-x) =\sin (x)$ and the change of variable $u=\pi/2-x$.

Answer (score 1):

$sin(x) = cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ and so for every continuous function $$\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 f(sin(x)) dx=\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 f(cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)) dx$$
Then taking $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ we have $du=-dx$ and we have
$$\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 f(cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)) dx = \int^0_\frac{\pi}{2} - f(cos(u)) du = \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 f(cos(u)) du $$

Answer (score 0):

In general,
$$\int^b_af(x)dx=\int^b_af(a+b-x)dx$$

In this case,
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_{0}f(\sin{x})dx
&=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}f(\sin{(\pi/2-x}))dx\\
&=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}f(\cos{x})dx\\
\end{align}
The "identity" is proved easily like so. Let $u=a+b-x$, then $du=-dx$. Hence
\begin{align}
\int^b_af(x)dx
&=-\int^a_bf(a+b-u)du\\
&=\int^b_af(a+b-u)du\\
&=\int^b_af(a+b-x)dx\\
\end{align}

Comment: You should probably add some parenthesis around $\pi/2 - x$ otherwise it looks a bit fishy